# Override default angular2 validator

Tags: validation, angular, dart

I want to create bindable version of `pattern` validation for `<input>`s of type text. Here is code:

```
const CUSTOM_PATTERN_VALIDATOR = const Provider(NG_VALIDATORS, useExisting: CustomPatternValidator, multi: true);

@Directive(
    selector:
    "[pattern][ngControl],[pattern][ngFormControl],[pattern][ngModel]",
    providers: const [CUSTOM_PATTERN_VALIDATOR])
class CustomPatternValidator implements Validator {
  ValidatorFn _validator;

  Map<String, dynamic> validate(AbstractControl c) {
    return this._validator(c);
  }

  @Input()
  set pattern(String value) {
    this._validator = Validators.pattern(value);
  }
}
```

But this validator does not disables default one, so value validates with `null` pattern at first, and control is always invalid. Is any way to do it correct?